# Qt - breakpoints don't work + "Unexpected GDB Exit"

Tags: qt, debugging, crash, gdb, breakpoints

I'm using Qt Creator 2.7.0 based on QT 4.8.4 (32 bit) with Ming 4.4 on windows. My Qt projects run without any problem in Release and Debug mode. However, when I try to debug, breakpoints don't work (the code does run successfully to the end) and I get the "Unexpected GDB Exit- The gdb process terminated" at the end. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I happened to have cygwin installed, so I configured my project to use the gdb that came with cygwin, just to see what happens. It works.

Comment: Possibly similar / related: [Why do i have this problem with breakpoints on GDB? GDB Stops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59311179) where GDB suspends itself.